# Is there an approach to combine multiple YOLO models into one single onnx runtime?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

I've multiple YOLOv8 models, having different sizes (i.e YOLOv8m, YOLOv8n, YOLOv8x). I'm doing object detection by exporting the model to `onnx` format and then making predictions. I can export them independently to `onnx` format.

But I want to ensemble those models. I know I can do this after making predictions from `onnx` format but for that there will be seperate `onnx` models for each `yolo` model. Is there any way to combine them and export as a single `onnx` file?

Is there something like:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.yolo1 = Yolo1() # my yolo model 1
        self.yolo2 = Yolo2() # my yolo model 2

    def forward(self, x):
        res1 = self.yolo1(x) # predictions from yolo model 1
        res2 = self.yolo2(x) # predictions from yolo model 2
        
        # perform predictions ensembling here
        return ensembled_score
```

I'm still new to onnx, so if this seems wrong, please correct me.